# Save Multiple Dataframes on excel workbook then Upload to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: python, excel, pandas, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

Good afternoon everyone,

I am trying to save multiple dataframes to an excel workbook on different sheets. Then upload that workbook to an Amazon S3 bucket. the code below works 99% of the way but the writer.save() cannot find my excel file on my S3 Bucket. Please assist if you know a way around this. thanks.

```
#Exports the data back to Excel - PLEASE READ LINE BELOW THIS CODE
bucket='sagemaker-bucket-xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx'
data_key = 'Provider Data.xlsx'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(data_location) #Targets the file where data is to be sent to
Comparison.to_excel(writer,'DATA') #Targets the worksheet data is to be sent too
df_current.to_excel(writer,'New Records') #Targets the worksheet data is to be sent too
df_prev.to_excel(writer,'Old Records') #Targets the worksheet data is to be sent too
df_same.to_excel(writer,'Same Records') #Targets the worksheet data is to be sent too
ALLCOUNT.to_excel(writer,'RPN Roll Up Count') #Targets the worksheet data is to be sent too
writer.save() #Saves files
```

error message is listed below.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://sagemaker-bucket-xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Provider Data.xlsx'

Comment: Is it because of the file name spaces?

Comment: @JamesDean i do not believe so, i can check

Answer (score 0):

s3 is not a standard file system that you can read and write with frameworks (such as Pandas) that are not aware of the data location different interface.

The simplest way is to write it locally to the file system of the notebook instance and then run `aws s3 cp` to upload it to s3.